# React table column definition becomes a string for some reason

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I'm defining a column for my table in react-table. I'm using Typescript so I need to define the type for my columns. For some reason when I define my columns in a custom made hook, the columns become a string when I import the hook and try to pass it to my Table component.

Below my custom hook where I define my columns:

```
const useBooksColumns = () => {
  const [sort, setSort] = useState("name");
  const [order, setOrder] = useState("asc");

  const columns: ColumnDef<Book>[] = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        header: "ID",
        accessorKey: "id",
      },
      {
        header: "ISBN",
        accessorKey: "volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers",
      },
      {
        header: "Title",
        accessorKey: "volumeInfo.title",
      },
      {
        header: "Authors",
        accessorKey: "volumeInfo.authors",
      },
      {
        header: "Publication date",
        accessorKey: "volumeInfo.publishedDate",
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  return [sort, order, columns];
};

export default useBooksColumns;
```

And here I try to use it:

```
  const [sort, order, columns] = useBookColumns();

      <Table
        data={response?.data.items ? response?.data.items : []}
        columns={columns}
 />
```

Now the message I'm getting is as follows: Type 'string | ColumnDef<Book, unknown>[]' is not assignable to type 'ColumnDef<any, any>[]'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ColumnDef<any, any>[]'.

Now changing the type to string | ColumnDef<Book, unknown>[] isn't an option since the useTable hook I'm using from tanstack/react-table doesn't take a string and gives me an error when I change it.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is not assuming an array literal as tuple per default so `[1, "hi"]` is inferred as `(string | number)[]` and not as `[number, string]`, to do so, the easiest way is to append it by `as const` so your example becomes:

```js
return [sort, order, columns] as const
```